# Comparing values with pictures

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm currently trying to make a simple comparing program but I'm stuck at the moment. I was wondering if it is possible to assign a value to an image namely 4 picture boxes, then comparing the values to see which box has a higher value. I'm fairly new to programming so I would really appreciate some examples.

here is an example of what im trying to achieve. 
[image]

1: Click two classes to compare

2: Then a message box appears showing which class has a higher value.

Comment: yes exactly for example the first picture could hold a value of 10 and the last on the right could be 25.

Comment: A picture box holds a picture, not a numeric value. You really need a class or something to hold metadata about the picture and compare the relevant metadata.

Comment: If you wants to keep it simple, you can use the Tag property to assign the numeric value, but, you will need to cast it. 
 You can use myPicture.Tag = 10;  but later you will need to do: int value = (int)myPicture.Tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Image` class has a `Tag` property:

> Gets or sets an object that provides additional data about the image.

```
var myImage = Bitmap.FromFile(@"c:\users\gwinney\desktop\9BYEo.jpg");
myImage.Tag = 4;

pictureBox1.Image = myImage;

var myNumber = Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Image.Tag);
```

---

The `PictureBox` has its own `Tag` property:

> Gets or sets the object that contains data about the control.

```
var myImage = Bitmap.FromFile(@"c:\users\gwinney\desktop\9BYEo.jpg");

pictureBox1.Image = myImage;
pictureBox1.Tag = 4;

var myNumber = Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Tag);
```

---

You could also create a `Dictionary` that holds meta data about each of your images. The key could be the name, or some other unique identifier about the image, then the value could be your number.

```
var myImageValues = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "ImageOne", 1 },
    { "ImageTwo", 4 },
    { "ImageThree", 8 },
    { "ImageFour", 2 }
};
```

Comment: Okay thank you so much.i'm gonna give it a try and will let you know how i get on.